# iOS share extension in chrome

Tags: google-chrome, safari, ios8-share-extension

Just added share extension to my app.
It's working fine in safari.
When launching it from Chrome the "ExtensionPreprocessingJS.js" isn't called.
as a result the following code is not invoked:

```
MyExtensionJavaScriptClass.prototype = {
run: function(arguments) {
    // Pass the baseURI of the webpage to the extension.
    arguments.completionFunction({"baseURI": document.baseURI});
},
```

Please advise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That behavior is documented as being a Safari option, not something that applies to every web browser.

> In Share extensions (on both platforms) and Action extensions (iOS only), you can give users access to web content **by asking Safari** to run a JavaScript file and return the results to the extension.

[Emphasis mine]

Comment: Thanks Tom, I know it. my question is can someone think of a workaround for working with chrome. obviously it's possible since some of the apps do support chrome share extension.

Answer (score 1):

Try to put/replace/add this to your info.plist of extension

`<dict>
        <key>NSExtensionAttributes</key>
        <dict>
            <key>NSExtensionActivationRule</key>
            <dict>
                <key>NSExtensionActivationSupportsText</key>
                <true/>
                <key>NSExtensionActivationSupportsWebPageWithMaxCount</key>
                <integer>1</integer>
                <key>NSExtensionActivationSupportsWebURLWithMaxCount</key>
                <integer>1</integer>
            </dict>
            <key>NSExtensionJavaScriptPreprocessingFile</key>
            <string>DemoPreprocessor</string>
        </dict>
        <key>NSExtensionMainStoryboard</key>
        <string>MainInterface</string>
        <key>NSExtensionPointIdentifier</key>
        <string>com.apple.share-services</string>
    </dict>`

Answer (score -3):

No need for that complicated stuff. This works both in Google Chrome and Safari:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    for item in extensionContext!.inputItems {
        if let attachments = item.attachments {
            for itemProvider in attachments! {
                itemProvider.loadItemForTypeIdentifier("public.url", options: nil, completionHandler: { (object, error) -> Void in
                    if object != nil {
                        println(object) //This is your URL
                    }
                })
            }
        }
    }
}
```